# Relation “actor” does not exist even though it does exist and have been using the same table throughout the day

Tags: postgresql

I’ve been using the table throughout the day for some reason now I come with the error that the relation does not exist. I’ve entered the table name exactly how it is. It worked earlier but now it gives me an error

Select *
From actor

Comment: You’re probably connected to a different database or something like that. The database is always right, you must be doing something different. But without any code, nobody can help you

Comment: Maybe wrong schema..